# Python interpret string as bytes

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string, containing some encrypted data, which is stored as bytes:

```
"b'\\}\x0e\t\x98\xde\x85\xaa\xb1'"
```

Everything I have tried so far either doesn't work, or just turns the string into bytes, which makes it even worse

```
b'b\'\\\\}\\x0e\\t\\x98\\xde\\x85\\xaa\\xb1
```

So, my question: How do I make python interpret a string containing bytes as bytes without changing the contents, or is this just not possible?

So, something like:

```
import magic
bytesInString = "b'\\}\x0e\t\x98\xde\x85\xaa\xb1'"
bytesOut = magic.str2bytes(bytesInString)
print(bytesOut) #b'\\}\x0e\t\x98\xde\x85\xaa\xb1'
```

Comment: Don't you just want `ast.literal_eval(r"b'\\}\x0e\t\x98\xde\x85\xaa\xb1'")`? Where is this string coming from?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks. The data was coming from an rsa encrypted message transferred over the internet, but was a string due to being part of a larger message that was also encrypted, leading to the decrypted larger message then containing the bytes of the encrypted message but in string form.